# Juno 5.0 install / Try it option freezes with boot errors on dell i3180

Tags: system-installation, release-juno, crash

I bought a new Dell at bestbuy with the reason on learning/using Linux and found that when I boot to the USB and Try the OS is works for a few seconds and freezes the computer.

I tried to install and the same thing happens as soon as its in the install process about 2 parts in.

There are error messages I managed to get on the boot screen that I need help figuring out a resolution to and a successful install.

Here is my PC (currently Win 10 Home)
AMD A6 9220e Radeon R4 1.6 GHz
4 GB MEMORY

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/reviews/dell-inspiron-11-6-laptop-amd-a6-4gb-memory-32gb-emmc-flash-memory-gray/6188326

Errors:

```
[    0.042676] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, invalid threshold interrupt offset 1 for b
ank 4, block 0 (MSR00000413=0xd00000000100000)
[    1.894345] couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[    1.894345] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[    2.931843] [drm:construct [amdgpu] *ERROR* construct: Invalid Connector Obj
ectID from Adapter Service for connector index:21
[    4.144382] [drm:hwss_wait_for_blank_complete [amdgpu]] *ERROR* DC: failed to 
blank crtc!
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just in case someone else was in the same boat I finally installed elementry os succesfully and its working great! I decided to update the bios on a hunch and turned off all secure, tpm and ueif boot options then boot only in f12 legacy to usb. I took a few tries as the installer froze but it finaly took.